# Did wizards participate in the First World War?

Tags: fantastic-beasts, fantastic-beasts-where-to-find-them

In the *Fantastic Beasts and Where To Find Them* film, it is mentionned that Newt Scamander's brother, Theseus, is a war hero. In another part, as Jacob meets wizards, they all seem to be impressed that he fought in it.

Although it seems improbable that WWI would pass unnoticed by the wizarding world, there aren't other clues as to whether other wizards participated in the war (at least in the MACUSA community).

So, did wizards participate in the First World War? Fighting each other or influencing the battles of their non-magic counterparts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes.

A piece of writing released earlier this year by *Harry Potter* book author JK Rowling on her website Pottermore (which [is considered](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/55370/31394) as canonical as the books, and more so than the films, for information on the Potterverse) confirms this:

> The wizards of America had played their part in the Great War of 1914-1918, even if the overwhelming majority of their No-Maj compatriots were ignorant of their contribution. As there were magical factions on both sides, their efforts were not decisive, but they won many victories in preventing additional loss of life, and in defeating their magical enemies.
>
> <sub>-- [Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/collection-episodic/history-of-magic-in-north-america-en?utm_source=en&utm_medium=WBCPartnerReferral&utm_campaign=WBC1_Mar2016), "1920s Wizarding America"</sub>

Comment: I think my next question will be: Why did they fought the war, since it seems that relations between magic and non-magic communities aren't the best.

Answer (score 0):

Wizards where forbidden from helping Muggles in WWI to prevent this sort of exposure. Nevertheless, Newt and his brother did participate in the war (Newt in charge of Ukranian Ironbellies)

- [Source](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/First_World_War)

Comment: The HP Wikia is a terrible source. Being editable by pretty much anyone, it's unreliable and often mistaken.

Comment: I guess the source of HP Wikia is this: https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-potter-family . Anyway, maybe I wasn't clear enough but I am asking about wizards in general, and not only British ones.